# Нельзя добавить Inline кнопки посредством markup в bot.send_photo. Есть ли другой способ?

Tags: python

```
@bot.message_handler(commands= ['start'])
def start(message):
   markup =types.InlineKeyboardMarkup( row_width=1 )
   btn = types.InlineKeyboardButton('  ЗАРАБОТАТЬ  ', callback_data= 'earn')
   markup.add(btn)
   photo = open ('sitepreview.jpg', 'rb')
   bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo, caption = '<b>введите сюда код Зарабатывай 
   РОБУКСЫ нажимая на КЛИК</b> '
                           '\n\n<b> Выводи на свой игровой счет ROBLOX</b>'
                           '\n\n<b> Жми на кнопку чтобы начать ⤵</b>️',
                            parse_mode='html')

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.